# Ripple (0.9.19) and BB10 WebWorks SDK 2.0.0.54 on Mac

Tags: blackberry-webworks, ripple

I cannot get Ripple to build using the SDK installed at the default location. I get the error message "Oh Snap! Build request failed with message: ./Applications/BlackBerry/BB10 WebWorks SDK 2.0.0.54 is not a valid path" (**EDIT**:THIS PROBLEM HAS BEEN FIXED BY REMOVING THE '.' - PLEASE SEE ERROR BELOW) - but that is where the SDK is installed.

I am following this tutorial here: http://www.patrickcatanzariti.com/2013/01/my-guide-to-developing-a-blackberry-html5-webworks-mobile-app/

but I am unsuccessful. I have also tried copying the BlackBerry10Simulator-BB10_2_0X-1791 folder from ./Documents/Virtual Machines into that folder and I still get the same error when trying to build, as well as another error when editing the settings: "No simulators found"

Has anyone built using this version of Ripple and BB10?

**EDIT**

I have changed the platform to BlackBerry 10 Webworks. Now the error appears on the command line:

> Checking output path /Users/username/Development/BlackBerry/BB_Output/
>   Path already exists
>   Running zip in /Users/username/Development/BlackBerry/Blackberry/BlackBerry
>   exec - "zip" -r "/Users/username/Development/BlackBerry/BB_Output/Output.zip" *
>   out:   adding: BlackBerry.zip
>   out:  (stored 0%)
>         adding: config.xml (deflated 63%)
>         adding: css/ (stored 0%)
>         adding: css/app.css (deflated 82%)
>         adding: images/ (stored 0%)
>         adding: images/image1.png
>   out:  (deflated 0%)
>         adding: images/Image3.png
>   out:  (stored 0%)
>         adding: images/smallImage.png
>   out:  (stored 0%)
>         adding: images/Thumbs.db
>   out:  (deflated 28%)
>         adding: js/
>   out:  (stored 0%)
>         adding: js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
>   out:  (deflated 65%)
>         adding: js/jquery.soap.js
>   out:  (deflated 69%)
>         adding: js/msisdn.js
>   out:  (deflated 66%)
>         adding: js/panic.js
>   out:  (deflated 76%)
>         adding: screen1.html
>   out:  (deflated 61%)
>         adding: screen2.html
>   out:  (deflated 74%)
>         adding: phoneNumber.html (deflated 66%)
>         adding: settings.html (deflated 57%)
>         adding: start.html (deflated 56%)
>   
>   error: Error: Cordova does not know 
> /Users/username/Development/BlackBerry/BB_Output/Output.zip; try help for a list of all the available commands.
>           at new CLI (/Applications/BlackBerry/BB10 WebWorks SDK 2.0.0.54/webworks-cli/node_modules/cordova/src/cli.js:114:15)
>           at new CLI (/Applications/BlackBerry/BB10 WebWorks SDK 2.0.0.54/webworks-cli/lib/cli.js:91:31)
>           at Object. (/Applications/BlackBerry/BB10 WebWorks SDK 2.0.0.54/webworks-cli/bin/webworks:4:16)
>           at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>           at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>           at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>           at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>           at startup (node.js:119:16)
>           at node.js:901:3

Comment: Have you tried removing the '.' period at the beginning of your paths? That doesn't seem right - that's usually a reference to the current working directory of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the short answer is that Ripple is *not* compatible with the WebWorks 2.x beta.

If it's just the packaging and deploying functionality you're hoping to make use of, I would recommend simply using CLI (Command Line Interface).

While CLI's tend to be scary, and unintuitive, I can assure you that the new WW 2.x CLI is super easy. I used to use Ripple for packaging and deploying until I got started with this new CLI. Now it's all command line, all the time for me.

Here's the easiest way to get it running, it's also what I do as well. More info available here as well https://github.com/apache/cordova-blackberry/tree/master/blackberry10

1. Put your device into Development Mode
2. Plug it into your Mac via USB

Open up Terminal and type the following:

1. Create a new project: "webworks create /Users/Chad/testapp com.chadsapps.testapp"
   This will create the sample "hello world" type of app, right out of the box
2. Change directory to the project: "cd /Users/Chad/testapp"
3. Deploy app to the device: "webworks run"
   If there is no debug token stored on your device, it'll auto-detect it via USB, and create one. You'll be asked to enter your Keystore password at the prompt.

You should now have the "hello world" app running on device!

If you're looking for the emulation/testing part of Ripple, you'll have to use the simulators instead (for WebWorks 2.0) which is available at https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/downloads/

Hope this helps, if not, please don't hesitate to ask ;)

-Chad
@chadtatro

Comment: Thanks Chad, I am actually looking to build and package the existing code that I have. I am looking to create the .bar file that I need. Is there a way to do this on the command line?

Comment: Yup absolutely. Check out the readme.md file here https://github.com/apache/cordova-blackberry/tree/master/blackberry10 it has all the steps you need to get up and running. It looks like a lot of info but it's actually pretty easy, just lots of information :)  If you'd like to check out some existing samples for reference, we have a lot over at https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/tree/WebWorks-2.0

Comment: Did this help you out?

Comment: No not really - there documentation is really not quite helpful. I found this to be the same when trying to develop for BB natively. They are using one name for a file / script in the docs, and a different one is installed, making it a nightmare to find out anything.

Comment: Turns out I just got a VM of my colleges' machine, and I compile and run from there. What a gip!

Answer (score 0):

Install nodes and try again. It will because your error logs shows startup node.js error something in node.js:119:116